# Problem Locating <blockquote> Images Around Quote With CSS

Tags: css, quote

On [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/organic-networking-the-5-point-guide/) I'm trying to position quote images around the block quote but they won't sit right.

This is the CSS:

```
    blockquote {
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#444;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 500px;
    background: #ff9999 url(/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/images/quoleft.png) left top no-repeat;
}
blockquote p {
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: #ff9999 url(/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/images/quoright.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

I want to keep the images the same size ideally. I just want to make the text stop overlapping the images. I tried specifying the width of the .blockquote as 500px but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas would be welcomed. Thanks - Tara

Comment: In a quick play with Firebug I get the desired results if: A) I increase the left padding of the blockquote-tag to at least 40px and B) disable the `padding: 0;` on `.entry p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. In order to see the images behind
   the text you should not specify a
   background color for the inner paragraph; make
   it `transparent` instead.
2. The specified padding is not applied due to another property (`.entry p`) which is more specific. You could set this blockquote padding to `!important` but that's generally not recommended, another option is to make this one more specific than the other (`.entry p`) by adding the `.entry` class. Be aware that only blockquotes with a parent `.entry` class will be selected this way. ([more info about specificity](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa062706.htm))

The css:

```
blockquote {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #444;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ff9999 url(/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/images/quoleft.png) left top no-repeat;
}

.entry blockquote p {
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: transparent url(/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/images/quoright.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That's much better! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this property:

```
.entry p {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: Tahoma,Georgia, Arial,century gothic,verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

I managed to get the following:

[image: Sample output]

Hope that helped (:

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser support that you need, you can try it without images, using CSS:

```
blockquote {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid blueviolet;
}
blockquote:after,
blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  vertical-align: -0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
blockquote:after {
  content: "”";
  margin-left: 0.05em;
}
blockquote:before {
  content: "“";
  margin-right: 0.05em;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

[image]

Live [example here](http://codepen.io/edinella/pen/xwpxNP?editors=110)
(Tested on Firefox and Chrome only)